# Error in callback in Jupiter Notebook with import PySpark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have EMR cluster and notebook. Since I want to work with PySpark, I changed my kernel to  PYSPARK.
Before

```
import pyspark
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-49d7c4e178f8> in <module>
----> 1 import pyspark

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

After the kernel was changed to PySpark

```
import pyspark

Error in callback <bound method WidgetKeeper.check_if_monitorable of <awseditorssparkmonitoringwidget.widgetkeeper.WidgetKeeper object at 0x7f37e11359d0>> (for pre_run_cell):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awseditorssparkmonitoringwidget-1.0-py3.7.egg/awseditorssparkmonitoringwidget/widgetkeeper.py in check_if_monitorable(self, info)

AttributeError: 'WidgetKeeper' object has no attribute 'request_target_endpoint'

The code failed because of a fatal error:
    'notebookId'.

Some things to try:
a) Make sure Spark has enough available resources for Jupyter to create a Spark context.
b) Contact your Jupyter administrator to make sure the Spark magics library is configured correctly.
c) Restart the kernel.
```

Where to find more about notebookId?
How to check Resources issue?